# How to mock Apache Camel Route before CamelContext is started in CamelSpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-boot-test, springmockito

Maybe a rather uncommon issue, but I'd like to **mock** certain Camel routes, in the **JUnit setup method**

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
}
```

**before** the

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

}
```

**is executed**, which seems to happen, as soon as the **CamelContext** is autowired

```
@Autowired
protected CamelContext camelContext;
```

**What do I need to do, to prevent autostarting of the Camel Context, in order to be able to mock my routes in the setup method and start it manually?**

Answer (score 0):

You can enable *advice with* in the unit test - then you need to start Camel manually.

https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html#_enabling_advice_during_testing